# does grpc service must have exactly one input parameter and one return value

Tags: grpc

let's say i have a proto file like this. can I define service like this

```
rpc SayHello () returns (Response) {} //service has no input
rpc SayHello (Request1,Request2) returns (Response) {}//service has two inputs
```

//.proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

service Greeter{
    rpc SayHello (Request) returns (Response) {}
}


message Request{
    string request = 1;
}

message Response{
    string response = 1;
}
```

Comment: As far as i know, in each rpc call, It uses http protocol to send the message to server so only one request and response message can be sent. You can add different type(int, string, float etc) values in request message.

Comment: If you are still interested in multiple parameters, check [nested messages](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#nested) in proto3.

Answer (score 57):

gRPC service methods have exactly one input message and exactly one output message. Typically, these messages are used as input and output to *only one* method. This is on purpose, as it allows easily adding new parameters later (to the messages) while maintaining backward compatibility.

If you don't want any input or output parameters, you can use the well-known proto [google.protobuf.Empty](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/empty.proto). However, this is discouraged as it prevents you from adding parameters to the method in the future. Instead, you would be encouraged to follow the normal practice of having a message for the request, but simply with no contents:

```
service Greeter {
    rpc SayHello (SayHelloRequest) returns (SayHelloResponse) {}
}

message SayHelloRequest {} // service has no input
```

Similarly, if you want two request parameters, just include both in the request message:

```
message SayHelloRequest { // service has two inputs
    string request = 1;
    string anotherRequestParam = 2;
}
```

Comment: "However, this is discouraged as it prevents you from adding parameters to the method in the future." <-- Is this really true? AFAICS you can switch to another message type later, as long as the new type is compatible on the wire with the old type (which any message type should be)? See also https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12468

Comment: Swapping the message type later can be wire-compatible, but would not generally be API-compatible. So it's not a change you can generally do. In a small project that you control client+server it could work. You may be interested in this presentation: https://kccncna17.sched.com/event/CU7e/modifying-grpc-services-over-time-i-eric-anderson-google (it links to slides and a recording).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Also thanks for the presentation link. I already looked through your slides before, but looking at the recording further clarifies things :-)

Comment: agree 100%.  I hated how thrift allowed multi-params.  We had to teach people in twitter every time..one message in, one message out always @EricAnderson .  For some reason though, thrift was way easier in the 'null' category for all languages and C++ has the isNameExist()/getName().  Instead protobuf(not grpc) seems to cater to C++ making Java, C#, Scala, etc. a bit more difficult in null(Option for scala) situations(which are never going to go away).

Comment: Its totally disappointing that we should break all of our old interfaces.