# gRPC: How to call a remote procedure with combination of static and stream parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python, proto3

I'm trying to transfer a file using gRPC. I can send the data, broken into chunks, using gRPC stream. I'm looking for way to also transfer the filename with the data. I'm sure there is an obvious solution that I'm missing. But here are a few approaches that I can think of

1. Sending filename with each chunk, which as the obvious disadvantage of retransmitting the same data. The .proto file will look like

```
service KeyValueStore {
    rpc upload (stream FileData) returns (UploadStatus) {}
}

message FileData {
    string filename = 1;
    bytes data = 2;
}
```

2. Sending the filename as the first chunk. The receiver will need to be aware of such encoding.

But I'm looking for a non-hacky solution.

I was hoping to have a solution like

```
service KeyValueStore {
    rpc upload (FileName, stream FileData) returns (UploadStatus) {}
}
```

But it's not possible and also discouraged according to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332432/3323839)

In general, is there a cleaner way to call a procedure with a combination of normal and stream parameters? or achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 3):

The post you linked is correct. Your input will be a single protocol buffer and in general, it should be named something like "FooRequest". The same is true for the response object, which should be called something like "FooResponse". Decoupling the request and response objects from their contents will give you room to change your API in a backwards-compatible manner over time.

The fact that we don't support multiple request types is not a barrier in practice, because protos can be nested arbitrarily. Consider an API like this.

```
message FileData {
    string filename = 1;
    bytes data = 2;
}

message UploadRequest {
    oneof payload {
        string filename = 1;
        FileData file_data = 2;
    }
}

service KeyValueStore {
    rpc upload (stream UploadRequest) returns (UploadResponse) {}
}
```

Of course, from the server's perspective, it is now possible for a misbehaving client to send a filename in the middle of the stream. Or, conversely, to start sending chunks of data without first sending a filename.

You could decide that a client *must* send a filename as the first message. Or perhaps it's okay as long as the filename is sent before the stream ends. Or perhaps sending the filename is entirely optional and not sending one will result in a default value for the filename.

Your decision on these points *will* be part of your API, but will *not* be enforced automatically by protobuf as an IDL. You'll need to explicitly handle these corner cases in your server code. Please remember though that, since these are API considerations, they *should* be written somewhere in your protobuf file. Do your very best to ensure that every message, RPC, and field has a clear and concise docstring.